# How to display route between two point in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Can any one please tell me how to show the route between two geo point in android application.If you can provide some code snippet.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't actually an Android question. You might get more luck if you add a Google Maps tag.

(Sorry, Roman, I was in a hurry)

Comment: The title ends with "in Android", why wouldn't you think it is an Android question? All the answers I can think of are pretty Android specific as well. Like using an ACTION_VIEW intent with the undocumented "google.navigation:" URI, or with a "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=42.35892,-71.05781&daddr=40.756054,-73.986951" type URI, which the Google Maps app intercepts when installed, or by pulling the KML results down off the HTTP version of Google Maps and then parsing the KML in Android and showing it in an Android MapView. Even with that last one, almost all of the code is Android related.